# Add model field to non-model serializer in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using **Django 2.x**

I have a serializer for validating the request. (Not ModelSerializer)

```
class ExecuteSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    database = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    query = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    user = serializers.HiddenField(
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )

    def validate(self, attrs):
        user = attrs.get('user', None)

        try:
            database = Database.objects.get(pk=attrs.get('database', None), collection__user=user)
        except Database.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError({
                'database': ['Does not exists']
            })

        attrs['database'] = database
        return attrs
```

`database` is reference to the `Database` model.

I want user to pass the database id in the `database` field but got is converted to `database` object after validation.

I tried to override the `validate()` method and assign the `database` object to the `database` field but it gives error

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Database'
```

Comment: The validate() requires dictionary of field values

Comment: Could you please provide the exception stack and relative codes you use `ExecuteSerializer` after `validate`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `IntegerField` for database field you shoud return int as database value in `validate` method, for example database.id:

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    user = attrs.get('user', None)

    try:
        database = Database.objects.get(pk=attrs.get('database', None), collection__user=user)
    except Database.DoesNotExist:
        raise ValidationError({
            'database': ['Does not exists']
        })

    attrs['database'] = database.id  # fix is here
    return attrs
```

Comment: I think the author should know this, and he just want to override validate method to get the database object even though we do not know why. If not, here even did not need `attrs['database'] = database.id` statement, because `database` in `attrs` is just the database `pk`.